# Same xpath returns different values on Centos, Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, xpath, centos, lxml

We're trying to port our application from a Centos environment into other linuxes, in particular Ubuntu. The application is python-based so there should be no problems, however we noticed an odd behaviour when parsing XPATHs.

Sample file:

```
<root>
    <outer>
        <inner>
            <el/>
        </inner>
        <inner>
            <el/>
        </inner>
    </outer>
</root>
```

Code:

```
from lxml import etree
r = etree.parse('foo.xml')
print 'One: ', r.xpath('.//el[2]')
print 'Two: ', r.xpath('(.//el)[2]')
```

On Centos (python 2.7.5):

```
One:  [<Element el at 0x25fdcf8>]
New version:  [<Element el at 0x25fdcf8>]
```

On RedHat Enterprise 6.6 (python 2.7.11)

```
One:  []
Two:  [<Element el at 0x7fa27198cd40>]
```

On Debian and Ubuntu (python 2.7.9 and 2.7.12):

```
One:  []
Two:  [<Element el at 0x7f94ed6cf200>]
```

This is the **same** code trying to access the second element `el`.

Debian, Ubuntu and Cents environment have lxml (installed from `pip`) version 3.6.4. When installing lxml it compiles it against libxml2 which is

On debian:

```
    $ dpkg -l | grep libxml2-dev
ii  libxml2-dev:amd64                     2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u2                 amd64
```

On centos:

```
$ rpm -q libxml2-devel
libxml2-devel-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64
```

RedHat runs etree 3.6.0:

```
$ rpm -q libxml2-devel
libxml2-devel-2.7.6-21.el6.x86_64
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Same python version?

Comment: @Hackerman no, in fact Debian ran on 2.7.9. Ubuntu on 2.7.12 and Centos 2.7.5. How could that be related?

Comment: What does import `lxml.etree;lxml.etree.LIBXML_COMPILED_VERSION` output on each? Because you have certain version now does not mean that is what it was compiled against

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The result is: `(2,9,1)` on centos and debian; `(2,9,3)` on ubuntu; `(2,7,6)` on redhat. It does not correlate with the different output as centos and debian return different values for the same xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result on CentOS is incorrect.

`libxml2` 2.9.0 introduced a regression, see [libxml 2.9.0 XPath evaluation issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=695699). It is fixed in 2.9.2 but not in 2.9.1.

Debian has integrated the patch in version 2.9.1+dfsg1-3:

> libxml2 (2.9.1+dfsg1-3) unstable; urgency=low
>
> - debian/patches/0007-Fix-XPath-optimization-with-predicates.patch:
>
>   - Upstream patch to fix XPath evaluation issue. (Closes: #713146)

Comment: so that's why it's giving the same result in RedHat (running 2.7.6) than Debian?

Comment: @lorenzog exactly, RHEL uses libxml2 2.7.6 and the bug has been introduced in libxml2 2.9.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That would have been impossible to find given that the bug reports use a slightly different notation "position()" rather than [n]. Either way, much appreciated.

Comment: Apparently I need to wait 20 hours to award the bounty.

Comment: @lorenzog That's most likely because bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day.

Comment: Yep :) just wanted to let you know why I'm not assigning you the bounty right away.